# How to change a matrix transformation relative to a new local space

Tags: matrices

If I have an arrow rotating around the y axis in it's own local space with matrix *T*, is it possible keep that rotation in world space consistent,  but change the local matrix to a new matrix *H* so that this new matrix has the arrow rotating for example around the z axis? So in this example the change between the local spaces would be 90 degrees in x or:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Which if I understand I can get by *T* * inverse(*H*) for the difference between the rotation matrices but that's as far as I have gotten.

Comment: You are using non-standard terms (which is to say I don't understand them).  What do "local space" and "world space" mean?  I can guess what they mean, and I can guess they appear in some localized literature such as a particular textbook or in some particular branch of applied science. But it would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: @kimchilover the world space is a representation in 3D space with origin [0,0,0], a local space can be positioned and oriented anywhere in that world space, but locally it's origin would also be [0,0,0]. So if the local space had coordinates  [1,0,0] in world space and a point P had coordinates [2,0,0] in world space, the point P relative to the local space would be [1,0,0]